# Column one under another one in a Plot

Tags: plotting, graphics, gui-construction

I would like to generate a graphic with the Sen,cos and tan function and 3 box on the left, each under the previous.

```
Labeled[listacampi1 = {PopupMenu[ris1, {"Seno","Coseno","Tangente"}]};
         Plot[{Sin[x],Cos[x],Tan[x]},{x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, PlotRange->{-4,4},ImageSize->Large],Column[listacampi1],Right];
```

Using that, I can generate one in the place where I want, but if I write in addition `,Column[listacampi1],Left` it doesn't work.

If I write instead `Column[{listacampi1,listacampi1}],Right` the output is like I want but there are the parenthesis that I don't want.

How can I do that?

Comment: The problem is that `listacampi1` is a `List`.  Either remove the braces from the definition of `listacampi1`, or use `Column[Flatten@{listacampi1,listacampi1}]`.  The first is almost certainly cleaner.

Comment: @jjc385 Flatten works, thank you

Comment: @jjc385 How can I put a label over each of them? Using Text[]?

Comment: I'm not an expert in plotting, and it's not entirely clear what you mean.  Your best bet is to ask a new question.

Comment: you could also draw an example of the result you want. Also supply code for working and not working examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
Labeled[listacampi1 = {PopupMenu[
ris1, {"Seno", "Coseno", "Tangente"}]};
Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x], Tan[x]}, {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, 
PlotRange -> {-4, 4}, ImageSize -> Large], 
Column[Row /@ {listacampi1, listacampi1}], Right]
```